# Query virtual fields using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model of a Person, with a virtual field `full_name` that combines first name, middle names and last name. This field is very useful when i want to find a person based on their whole name. I've however read that I can't query on virtual fields. First of all, is this true? Why? What is the best approach here if I want to do something like this:

```
router.get("/:searchTerm", (req, res) => {
   const st = req.params.searchTerm;

    Person.find({full_name: {$regex: st, $options: "i"}}, (err, ppl) => {
        res.json(ppl);
    }).limit(30);
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using regex to search the full names that match a search term will be a nightmare in your case. Because you'll have to split the search term into individual keywords and then use regex to match each keyword on both the first name and last name fields. Aggregation might help with the query complexity a little, but then you'll have to worry about performance caveats. Regex matching in itself is slow, and then aggregation on a large data set will be even slower.

So the best approach should be using text search. Create a text index including both the first name and last name fields on the collection and then use a simple text search to retrieve the values that match the search term. Here are some resources for you to get started on.

- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/link-text-indexes/
- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/text-search-operators/